# Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.0.1

Tags: ffmpeg

when I installed react-native-ffmpeg and executed react-native run-android, the following error was reported
[image: https://github.com/tanersener/react-native-ffmpeg/issues/254]

I used the newly created react native project. When I haven’t installed this package, everything is normal.
Unfortunately, when I installed this package without any operation, I got an error.
Can you give me some suggestions？

Expected behavior
react-native run-android success

Current behavior
react-native run-android failed

Screenshots
This is all my dependencies, this is the new start of react native
[image]

Environment
"react": "17.0.1",
"react-native": "0.64.2",
"react-native-ffmpeg": "^0.5.1"

Please give me some suggestions, thank you very much, it has troubled me for a long time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason is because react-native-ffmpeg specifies the Google address, which makes it inaccessible
[image]